# Proof validation $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\right) = {1\over e}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, summation

> Prove the following limit: 
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\right) = {1\over e}
> $$

The instrumentation I have so far is:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n = e \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-{1\over n}\right)^n = {1\over e} \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n {1\over k!} = e
$$

I would like to keep away from using:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n {x^k \over k!}  = e^x
$$
because that is what I essentially want to prove. **Derivatives (Taylor series) are not allowed as well**. This problem is from limits section.

My argumentation is as follows. Define $x_n$:
$$
x_n = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}
$$
Define $y_n$:
$$
y_n = \left(1-{1\over n}\right)^n
$$

Let's see whether $x_n$ is convergent. Try Cauchy Criterion for $m>n$:
$$
\begin{align}
|x_n - x_m| &= \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^m{(-1)^k\over k!}\right| \\
&= \left|\sum_{k\ \text{even}}^m{1\over k!} - \sum_{k\ \text{odd}}^m{1\over k!}\right| \\
&\le \sum_{k=n+1}^m{1\over k!} \\
&\le \sum_{k=n+1}^m{1\over k(k-1)} \\ 
&= {1\over n} - {1\over m} \\
&< {1\over n} < \epsilon
\end{align}
$$

So $x_n$ converges and $y_n$ is also known to be convergent. Consider the difference:
$$
z_n = x_n - y_n
$$
Rewrite $y_n$ using Binomial expansion:
$$
y_n = \left(1-{1\over n}\right)^n \\
= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}\left({-1\over n}\right)^k \\
= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\frac{\prod_{i=1}^k(n-(i-1))}{k!n^k}\\
= 1 - 1 + {1\over 2!}\left(1-{1\over n}\right) - {1\over 3!}\left(1-{1\over n}\right)\left(1-{2\over n}\right) + \cdots + {1\over n!}\left(1-{1\over n}\right)\cdot \cdots \cdot \left(1-{n-1\over n}\right)
$$
So:
$$
z_n = {1\over 2!} - {1\over 2!}\left(1-{1\over n}\right) - {1\over 3!} + {1\over 3!}\left(1-{1\over n}\right)\left(1-{2\over n}\right) + \cdots
$$

Now if we let $n\to\infty$ then $z_n$ tends to $0$:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n = 0
$$

Which by convergence of $x_n$ and $y_n$ means:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}y_n = {1\over e}
$$

This one is monstrous and I have doubts whether it's valid. So I'm kindly asking to confirm my reasoning is fine and/or point to mistakes. Also I would appreciate if someone could share a more elegant proof. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the Edit to Clarify that part! :) Btw, I think that your proof is nice, but I suspect a geometrical proof for it!... Would that work?

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha I would like to stick to algebraic proof, yet it may certainly be interpreted from a geometric perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:
Using Cauchy product we have
$$\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \cdot \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{1}{k!} = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k}.$$
Now one only has to show that for $n > 0$ we have
$$\sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k} = 0$$
which follows easily from the binomial theorem, i.e.
$$0 = (1 + (-1))^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k} 1^{n-k} (-1)^k = \sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k}.$$
For $n = 0$ the sum is obviously equal to $1$. Thus
$$\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \cdot e = \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \cdot \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{1}{k!} = 1$$
which shows
$$\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} = \frac{1}{e}.$$

Comment: Smart use of the Cauchy product, never thought of it your way. Thank you!